# Fail in calling Enable-Migrations for a generic DbContext class

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations, generic-programming

Let's assume that I have this Entity Framework (v6.0) DbContext-based class, sitting in the "Food.Common" assembly:

```
public class FoodContext<T> : DbContext where T : Food<T>
{
    public FoodContext() : base("MyConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<T> FoodElements { get; set; }
}
```

The above `Food` generic class is also sitting in the "Food.Common" assembly, and it is defined as:

```
public class Food<T> where T : Food<T>
{
    // some code here...

    public virtual T Copy()
    {
       // object copy goes here...
    }
}
```

Also, I have this class which inherits from `Food<T>` and sits on the "Food.Extras" assembly:

```
public class HealthyFood : Food<HealthyFood>
{
    // some code here...

    public override HealthyFood Copy()
    {
       var baseCopy = base.Copy();
       // extending the baseCopy with more data...
    }
}
```

Now, I can easily instantiate and use the `FoodContext<T>` context like this:

```
using (var context = new FoodContext<HealthyFood>())
{
   // some CRUD for "healthy food" goes here...
}
```

and the appropriate table is automatically created by EF in the database.
**The problem is**: when trying to call the "Enable-Migrations" command after updating the HealthyFood class (the model), I get notified by the Package Manager Console that "**No context type was found in the assembly Food.Common**".

My suspicion is that since the "Food.Common" does not contain a concrete (non generic) DbContext-based class, the "Enable-Migrations" thinks there's no context type inside this assembly at all.

So, how can I tell the Enable-Migrations that I want to update a concrete DbContext class (such as the `FoodContext<HealthyFood>`)?

Already tried `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Food.Common.FoodContext<HealthyFood>` with no luck...